# Android intent based on file type

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types

I am trying to develop a folder browser for Android..
A folder can have any type of files, i.e a doc file, txt file, mp3, avi, apk file and so on..
How do i launch a specific application based on the file that the user has clicked...
i mean how do i construct a file type based intent...
Thanks
Prashanth

Answer (score 2):

Just set the type of the Intent, for example: `intent.setType("video/mpeg");`.

Edit: Use [MimeTypeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html) to dynamically get the MIME-Type for a file.

Comment: this can be done for known file types...suppose there are new file types say .rtf and the user has installed some app to display .rtf files.. then i will have to re-code my app to run such files...

Comment: No, because you can get the MIME-Type from a file ;) See my edit!

Comment: Hi. Can you please tell me if it is possible to show a preview of the file based on the mime type. I mean if it is a video, i want to show a preview, and if it is a pdf, i just want to show a icon and let the user open it by clicking on it. Is this possible?

Comment: That's possible but I'm quite sure that you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Create one activity. Where you will find the extension of file whether mp3 or dic etc. Based on the extension call another activity from this activity.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: i dont want to hard code the extension based activity launch in my app..cant it be done by the system itself..i want to use generic one, so that at some point in future if the user installs an app for some ".abc" extension, then using my app and clicking a ".abc" file must launch that app..

Answer (score 0):

may be like this...because I'm trying it on my code...

```
//differentiate file type
    String filename = o.getName();
    String filenameArray[] = filename.split("\\.");
    String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    if (extension.contains("png") || extension.contains("gif") || extension.contains("jpg") 
            || extension.contains("jpeg") || extension.contains("bmp"))
    {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + o.getPath()), "image/*");
    }
    if (extension.contains("txt") || extension.contains("csv") || extension.contains("xml"))
    {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + o.getPath()), "text/*");
    }
    if (extension.contains("pdf"))
    {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + o.getPath()), "application/pdf");
    }
    if (extension.contains("doc") || extension.contains("docx"))
    {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + o.getPath()), "application/msword");
    }
    if (extension.contains("mp3") || extension.contains("wav") || extension.contains("oog") 
            || extension.contains("mid") || extension.contains("amr") || extension.contains("midi"))
    {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + o.getPath()), "audio/*");
    }
    if (extension.contains("mpeg") || extension.contains("3gp"))
    {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + o.getPath()), "video/*");
    }
```

i'm still looking for the short code, but i hope this code can help you...

Answer (score 0):

I found one. Maybe this could help you:

```
Intent intent= new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

File file = new File(filePath);

MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".")+1);
String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
```